# How to include http library in Android Project using M preview in Eclipse ant build

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

With Android M Google has deprecated support for http library. To support existing applications use this library they have documented that using GRADLE build we can add support to http library by using following parameter.

```
android{
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

How can we achieve the same in Eclipse environment using ant build ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just copy

your Android SDK folder/sdk/platforms/android-23/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar

file to your project's Libs folder